# MediaPlayer is in playing state but plays nothing?

Tags: android, audio, media-player, android-mediaplayer, http-live-streaming

I am testing my app for extreme cases where the user might have bad internet connection so heres what I did.

I have been bottlenecking my internet so that my testing device receives very less bandwidth to stream a url.

Now here is the case : 
The media player buffers well for like 5 times and plays the stream. However after few more buffering state and the player goes into this numb mode where I cant even stop it, the player button remains static.
After thorough examination I found this from the verbose :

```
V/MediaPlayer[Native]: isPlaying: 1
```

Which means the mediaplayer is fooling my app by saying that it is still playing even though there is no sound coming from the app. Lulz?

Now comes the funny part "the player will start playing the stream only after like 5-10 mins" (when I stop bottlenecking the internet)

listeners attached to the mediaplayer :

1. MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener
2. MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener
3. MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener / [Also tried OnBufferListener - Same
   results]

Any type of help/Suggestion appreciated 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: post your code too

Comment: @VivekMishra its too long to post ! already listed the things I am using

Comment: can someone help me with this :')